# SPI2 on the bluepill STM32F103C8 doesn't work

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32cubemx

For a while, I have been trying to interface a 1.8 TFT ST7735 to my STM32F103C8 bluepill using SPI2 and HAL.
I tried SPI1 and has worked perfectly, but because I am interfacing LoRa to the bluepill using SPI1, I have to use SPI2 for the TFT.
I don't want to use many slaves on the same SPI1, it may affect the performance of LoRa.
I searched on the net for some examples about SPI2 but I couldn't find something.
So please if someone know how to get it to work or has an idea please share it with me.
I am using STM32CubeMX and Keil IDE to code.

Capture for SPI2:

[image: logic analyser capture]

There is no toggling only first when I reset the bluepill

I have debug it using Keil and find out that it hangs in HAL_SPI_Transmit() function.
In this function it initializes everything correctly or it seems like that.
After that it tries to send data ( 8 bit mode ) it hangs in timeout because the TXE flag is not set.

The tutorial I use: [Controllertech - ST7735 1.8″ TFT Display with STM32](https://controllerstech.com/st7735-1-8-tft-display-with-stm32/)

And the main code:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

#include <string.h>
#include "st7735.h"
#include "GFX_FUNCTIONS.h"
#include "fonts.h"

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    
    ST7735_Init();

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        
        ST7735_FillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);
        ST7735_WriteString(3*18, 10, "Hello", Font_7x10, ST7735_RED, ST7735_BLACK);
        ST7735_WriteString(5, 3*10, "from", Font_11x18, ST7735_GREEN, ST7735_BLACK);
        ST7735_WriteString(0, 3*10+3*10, "Kurdistan", Font_16x26, ST7735_YELLOW, ST7735_BLACK);
        HAL_Delay(3000);
        ST7735_FillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);
        drawCircle(50, 55, 20, ST7735_GREEN);
        drawCircle(50, 55, 21, ST7735_GREEN);
        drawCircle(50, 55, 22, ST7735_GREEN);
        drawCircle(50, 55, 23, ST7735_GREEN);
        drawCircle(50, 55, 24, ST7735_GREEN);
        drawCircle(50, 55, 25, ST7735_RED);
        drawCircle(50, 55, 26, ST7735_RED);
        drawCircle(50, 55, 27, ST7735_RED);
        drawCircle(50, 55, 28, ST7735_RED);
        HAL_Delay(4000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

The header file st7735.h:

```
#ifndef __ST7735_H__
#define __ST7735_H__

#include "fonts.h"
#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ST7735_MADCTL_MY  0x80
#define ST7735_MADCTL_MX  0x40
#define ST7735_MADCTL_MV  0x20
#define ST7735_MADCTL_ML  0x10
#define ST7735_MADCTL_RGB 0x00
#define ST7735_MADCTL_BGR 0x08
#define ST7735_MADCTL_MH  0x04

/*** Redefine if necessary ***/
#define ST7735_SPI_PORT hspi2
extern SPI_HandleTypeDef ST7735_SPI_PORT;

#define ST7735_RES_Pin       GPIO_PIN_10
#define ST7735_RES_GPIO_Port GPIOB
#define ST7735_CS_Pin        GPIO_PIN_1
#define ST7735_CS_GPIO_Port  GPIOB
#define ST7735_DC_Pin        GPIO_PIN_0
#define ST7735_DC_GPIO_Port  GPIOB

//#define ST7735_SPI_PORT hspi2
//extern SPI_HandleTypeDef ST7735_SPI_PORT;
//
//#define ST7735_RES_Pin       GPIO_PIN_2
//#define ST7735_RES_GPIO_Port GPIOA
//#define ST7735_CS_Pin        GPIO_PIN_4
//#define ST7735_CS_GPIO_Port  GPIOA
//#define ST7735_DC_Pin        GPIO_PIN_3
//#define ST7735_DC_GPIO_Port  GPIOA


// AliExpress/eBay 1.8" display, default orientation

#define ST7735_IS_160X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  128
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 160
#define ST7735_XSTART 0
#define ST7735_YSTART 0
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MX | ST7735_MADCTL_MY)


// AliExpress/eBay 1.8" display, rotate right
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  160
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 128
#define ST7735_XSTART 0
#define ST7735_YSTART 0
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MY | ST7735_MADCTL_MV)
*/

// AliExpress/eBay 1.8" display, rotate left
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  160
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 128
#define ST7735_XSTART 0
#define ST7735_YSTART 0
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MX | ST7735_MADCTL_MV)
*/

// AliExpress/eBay 1.8" display, upside down
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  128
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 160
#define ST7735_XSTART 0
#define ST7735_YSTART 0
#define ST7735_ROTATION (0)
*/

// WaveShare ST7735S-based 1.8" display, default orientation
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  128
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 160
#define ST7735_XSTART 2
#define ST7735_YSTART 1
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MX | ST7735_MADCTL_MY | ST7735_MADCTL_RGB)
*/

// WaveShare ST7735S-based 1.8" display, rotate right
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  160
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 128
#define ST7735_XSTART 1
#define ST7735_YSTART 2
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MY | ST7735_MADCTL_MV | ST7735_MADCTL_RGB)
*/

// WaveShare ST7735S-based 1.8" display, rotate left
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  160
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 128
#define ST7735_XSTART 1
#define ST7735_YSTART 2
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MX | ST7735_MADCTL_MV | ST7735_MADCTL_RGB)
*/

// WaveShare ST7735S-based 1.8" display, upside down
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  128
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 160
#define ST7735_XSTART 2
#define ST7735_YSTART 1
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_RGB)
*/

// 1.44" display, default orientation
//#define ST7735_IS_128X128 1
//#define ST7735_WIDTH  128
//#define ST7735_HEIGHT 128
//#define ST7735_XSTART 2
//#define ST7735_YSTART 3
//#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MX | ST7735_MADCTL_MY | ST7735_MADCTL_BGR)

// 1.44" display, rotate right
/*
#define ST7735_IS_128X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  128
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 128
#define ST7735_XSTART 3
#define ST7735_YSTART 2
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MY | ST7735_MADCTL_MV | ST7735_MADCTL_BGR)
*/

// 1.44" display, rotate left
/*
#define ST7735_IS_128X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  128
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 128
#define ST7735_XSTART 1
#define ST7735_YSTART 2
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MX | ST7735_MADCTL_MV | ST7735_MADCTL_BGR)
*/

// 1.44" display, upside down
/*
#define ST7735_IS_128X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  128
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 128
#define ST7735_XSTART 2
#define ST7735_YSTART 1
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_BGR)
*/

// mini 160x80 display (it's unlikely you want the default orientation)
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X80 1
#define ST7735_XSTART 26
#define ST7735_YSTART 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  80
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 160 
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MX | ST7735_MADCTL_MY | ST7735_MADCTL_BGR)
*/

// mini 160x80, rotate left
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X80 1
#define ST7735_XSTART 1
#define ST7735_YSTART 26
#define ST7735_WIDTH  160
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 80
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MX | ST7735_MADCTL_MV | ST7735_MADCTL_BGR)
*/

// mini 160x80, rotate right 
/*
#define ST7735_IS_160X80 1
#define ST7735_XSTART 1
#define ST7735_YSTART 26
#define ST7735_WIDTH  160
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 80
#define ST7735_ROTATION (ST7735_MADCTL_MY | ST7735_MADCTL_MV | ST7735_MADCTL_BGR)
*/

/****************************/

#define ST7735_NOP     0x00
#define ST7735_SWRESET 0x01
#define ST7735_RDDID   0x04
#define ST7735_RDDST   0x09

#define ST7735_SLPIN   0x10
#define ST7735_SLPOUT  0x11
#define ST7735_PTLON   0x12
#define ST7735_NORON   0x13

#define ST7735_INVOFF  0x20
#define ST7735_INVON   0x21
#define ST7735_GAMSET  0x26
#define ST7735_DISPOFF 0x28
#define ST7735_DISPON  0x29
#define ST7735_CASET   0x2A
#define ST7735_RASET   0x2B
#define ST7735_RAMWR   0x2C
#define ST7735_RAMRD   0x2E

#define ST7735_PTLAR   0x30
#define ST7735_COLMOD  0x3A
#define ST7735_MADCTL  0x36

#define ST7735_FRMCTR1 0xB1
#define ST7735_FRMCTR2 0xB2
#define ST7735_FRMCTR3 0xB3
#define ST7735_INVCTR  0xB4
#define ST7735_DISSET5 0xB6

#define ST7735_PWCTR1  0xC0
#define ST7735_PWCTR2  0xC1
#define ST7735_PWCTR3  0xC2
#define ST7735_PWCTR4  0xC3
#define ST7735_PWCTR5  0xC4
#define ST7735_VMCTR1  0xC5

#define ST7735_RDID1   0xDA
#define ST7735_RDID2   0xDB
#define ST7735_RDID3   0xDC
#define ST7735_RDID4   0xDD

#define ST7735_PWCTR6  0xFC

#define ST7735_GMCTRP1 0xE0
#define ST7735_GMCTRN1 0xE1

// Color definitions
#define ST7735_BLACK   0x0000
#define ST7735_BLUE    0x001F
#define ST7735_RED     0xF800
#define ST7735_GREEN   0x07E0
#define ST7735_CYAN    0x07FF
#define ST7735_MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define ST7735_YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define ST7735_WHITE   0xFFFF
#define ST7735_COLOR565(r, g, b) (((r & 0xF8) << 8) | ((g & 0xFC) << 3) | ((b & 0xF8) >> 3))

typedef enum {
    GAMMA_10 = 0x01,
    GAMMA_25 = 0x02,
    GAMMA_22 = 0x04,
    GAMMA_18 = 0x08
} GammaDef;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// call before initializing any SPI devices
void ST7735_Unselect();

void ST7735_Init(void);
void ST7735_DrawPixel(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t color);
void ST7735_WriteString(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, const char* str, FontDef font, uint16_t color, uint16_t bgcolor);
void ST7735_FillRectangle(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, uint16_t color);
void ST7735_FillRectangleFast(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, uint16_t color);
void ST7735_FillScreen(uint16_t color);
void ST7735_FillScreenFast(uint16_t color);
void ST7735_DrawImage(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, const uint16_t* data);
void ST7735_InvertColors(bool invert);
void ST7735_SetGamma(GammaDef gamma);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __ST7735_H__
```

And the source file st7735.c:

```
#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"
#include "st7735.h"
//#include "malloc.h"
#include "string.h"

#define DELAY 0x80

// based on Adafruit ST7735 library for Arduino
static const uint8_t
  init_cmds1[] = {            // Init for 7735R, part 1 (red or green tab)
    15,                       // 15 commands in list:
    ST7735_SWRESET,   DELAY,  //  1: Software reset, 0 args, w/delay
      150,                    //     150 ms delay
    ST7735_SLPOUT ,   DELAY,  //  2: Out of sleep mode, 0 args, w/delay
      255,                    //     500 ms delay
    ST7735_FRMCTR1, 3      ,  //  3: Frame rate ctrl - normal mode, 3 args:
      0x01, 0x2C, 0x2D,       //     Rate = fosc/(1x2+40) * (LINE+2C+2D)
    ST7735_FRMCTR2, 3      ,  //  4: Frame rate control - idle mode, 3 args:
      0x01, 0x2C, 0x2D,       //     Rate = fosc/(1x2+40) * (LINE+2C+2D)
    ST7735_FRMCTR3, 6      ,  //  5: Frame rate ctrl - partial mode, 6 args:
      0x01, 0x2C, 0x2D,       //     Dot inversion mode
      0x01, 0x2C, 0x2D,       //     Line inversion mode
    ST7735_INVCTR , 1      ,  //  6: Display inversion ctrl, 1 arg, no delay:
      0x07,                   //     No inversion
    ST7735_PWCTR1 , 3      ,  //  7: Power control, 3 args, no delay:
      0xA2,
      0x02,                   //     -4.6V
      0x84,                   //     AUTO mode
    ST7735_PWCTR2 , 1      ,  //  8: Power control, 1 arg, no delay:
      0xC5,                   //     VGH25 = 2.4C VGSEL = -10 VGH = 3 * AVDD
    ST7735_PWCTR3 , 2      ,  //  9: Power control, 2 args, no delay:
      0x0A,                   //     Opamp current small
      0x00,                   //     Boost frequency
    ST7735_PWCTR4 , 2      ,  // 10: Power control, 2 args, no delay:
      0x8A,                   //     BCLK/2, Opamp current small & Medium low
      0x2A,  
    ST7735_PWCTR5 , 2      ,  // 11: Power control, 2 args, no delay:
      0x8A, 0xEE,
    ST7735_VMCTR1 , 1      ,  // 12: Power control, 1 arg, no delay:
      0x0E,
    ST7735_INVOFF , 0      ,  // 13: Don't invert display, no args, no delay
    ST7735_MADCTL , 1      ,  // 14: Memory access control (directions), 1 arg:
      ST7735_ROTATION,        //     row addr/col addr, bottom to top refresh
    ST7735_COLMOD , 1      ,  // 15: set color mode, 1 arg, no delay:
      0x05 },                 //     16-bit color

#if (defined(ST7735_IS_128X128) || defined(ST7735_IS_160X128))
  init_cmds2[] = {            // Init for 7735R, part 2 (1.44" display)
    2,                        //  2 commands in list:
    ST7735_CASET  , 4      ,  //  1: Column addr set, 4 args, no delay:
      0x00, 0x00,             //     XSTART = 0
      0x00, 0x7F,             //     XEND = 127
    ST7735_RASET  , 4      ,  //  2: Row addr set, 4 args, no delay:
      0x00, 0x00,             //     XSTART = 0
      0x00, 0x7F },           //     XEND = 127
#endif // ST7735_IS_128X128

#ifdef ST7735_IS_160X80
  init_cmds2[] = {            // Init for 7735S, part 2 (160x80 display)
    3,                        //  3 commands in list:
    ST7735_CASET  , 4      ,  //  1: Column addr set, 4 args, no delay:
      0x00, 0x00,             //     XSTART = 0
      0x00, 0x4F,             //     XEND = 79
    ST7735_RASET  , 4      ,  //  2: Row addr set, 4 args, no delay:
      0x00, 0x00,             //     XSTART = 0
      0x00, 0x9F ,            //     XEND = 159
    ST7735_INVON, 0 },        //  3: Invert colors
#endif

  init_cmds3[] = {            // Init for 7735R, part 3 (red or green tab)
    4,                        //  4 commands in list:
    ST7735_GMCTRP1, 16      , //  1: Gamma Adjustments (pos. polarity), 16 args, no delay:
      0x02, 0x1c, 0x07, 0x12,
      0x37, 0x32, 0x29, 0x2d,
      0x29, 0x25, 0x2B, 0x39,
      0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x10,
    ST7735_GMCTRN1, 16      , //  2: Gamma Adjustments (neg. polarity), 16 args, no delay:
      0x03, 0x1d, 0x07, 0x06,
      0x2E, 0x2C, 0x29, 0x2D,
      0x2E, 0x2E, 0x37, 0x3F,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x10,
    ST7735_NORON  ,    DELAY, //  3: Normal display on, no args, w/delay
      10,                     //     10 ms delay
    ST7735_DISPON ,    DELAY, //  4: Main screen turn on, no args w/delay
      100 };                  //     100 ms delay

static void ST7735_Select() {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ST7735_CS_GPIO_Port, ST7735_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}

void ST7735_Unselect() {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ST7735_CS_GPIO_Port, ST7735_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

static void ST7735_Reset() {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ST7735_RES_GPIO_Port, ST7735_RES_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(5);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ST7735_RES_GPIO_Port, ST7735_RES_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

static void ST7735_WriteCommand(uint8_t cmd) {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ST7735_DC_GPIO_Port, ST7735_DC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&ST7735_SPI_PORT, &cmd, sizeof(cmd), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

static void ST7735_WriteData(uint8_t* buff, size_t buff_size) {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ST7735_DC_GPIO_Port, ST7735_DC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&ST7735_SPI_PORT, buff, buff_size, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

static void ST7735_ExecuteCommandList(const uint8_t *addr) {
    uint8_t numCommands, numArgs;
    uint16_t ms;

    numCommands = *addr++;
    while(numCommands--) {
        uint8_t cmd = *addr++;
        ST7735_WriteCommand(cmd);

        numArgs = *addr++;
        // If high bit set, delay follows args
        ms = numArgs & DELAY;
        numArgs &= ~DELAY;
        if(numArgs) {
            ST7735_WriteData((uint8_t*)addr, numArgs);
            addr += numArgs;
        }

        if(ms) {
            ms = *addr++;
            if(ms == 255) ms = 500;
            HAL_Delay(ms);
        }
    }
}

static void ST7735_SetAddressWindow(uint8_t x0, uint8_t y0, uint8_t x1, uint8_t y1) {
    // column address set
    ST7735_WriteCommand(ST7735_CASET);
    uint8_t data[] = { 0x00, x0 + ST7735_XSTART, 0x00, x1 + ST7735_XSTART };
    ST7735_WriteData(data, sizeof(data));

    // row address set
    ST7735_WriteCommand(ST7735_RASET);
    data[1] = y0 + ST7735_YSTART;
    data[3] = y1 + ST7735_YSTART;
    ST7735_WriteData(data, sizeof(data));

    // write to RAM
    ST7735_WriteCommand(ST7735_RAMWR);
}

void ST7735_Init() {
    ST7735_Select();
    HAL_Delay(100);
    ST7735_Reset();
    HAL_Delay(100);
    ST7735_ExecuteCommandList(init_cmds1);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    ST7735_ExecuteCommandList(init_cmds2);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    ST7735_ExecuteCommandList(init_cmds3);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    ST7735_Unselect();
}

void ST7735_DrawPixel(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t color) {
    if((x >= ST7735_WIDTH) || (y >= ST7735_HEIGHT))
        return;

    ST7735_Select();

    ST7735_SetAddressWindow(x, y, x+1, y+1);
    uint8_t data[] = { color >> 8, color & 0xFF };
    ST7735_WriteData(data, sizeof(data));

    ST7735_Unselect();
}

static void ST7735_WriteChar(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, char ch, FontDef font, uint16_t color, uint16_t bgcolor) {
    uint32_t i, b, j;

    ST7735_SetAddressWindow(x, y, x+font.width-1, y+font.height-1);

    for(i = 0; i < font.height; i++) {
        b = font.data[(ch - 32) * font.height + i];
        for(j = 0; j < font.width; j++) {
            if((b << j) & 0x8000)  {
                uint8_t data[] = { color >> 8, color & 0xFF };
                ST7735_WriteData(data, sizeof(data));
            } else {
                uint8_t data[] = { bgcolor >> 8, bgcolor & 0xFF };
                ST7735_WriteData(data, sizeof(data));
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
Simpler (and probably slower) implementation:

static void ST7735_WriteChar(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, char ch, FontDef font, uint16_t color) {
    uint32_t i, b, j;

    for(i = 0; i < font.height; i++) {
        b = font.data[(ch - 32) * font.height + i];
        for(j = 0; j < font.width; j++) {
            if((b << j) & 0x8000)  {
                ST7735_DrawPixel(x + j, y + i, color);
            } 
        }
    }
}
*/

void ST7735_WriteString(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, const char* str, FontDef font, uint16_t color, uint16_t bgcolor) {
    ST7735_Select();

    while(*str) {
        if(x + font.width >= ST7735_WIDTH) {
            x = 0;
            y += font.height;
            if(y + font.height >= ST7735_HEIGHT) {
                break;
            }

            if(*str == ' ') {
                // skip spaces in the beginning of the new line
                str++;
                continue;
            }
        }

        ST7735_WriteChar(x, y, *str, font, color, bgcolor);
        x += font.width;
        str++;
    }

    ST7735_Unselect();
}

void ST7735_FillRectangle(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, uint16_t color) {
    // clipping
    if((x >= ST7735_WIDTH) || (y >= ST7735_HEIGHT)) return;
    if((x + w - 1) >= ST7735_WIDTH) w = ST7735_WIDTH - x;
    if((y + h - 1) >= ST7735_HEIGHT) h = ST7735_HEIGHT - y;

    ST7735_Select();
    ST7735_SetAddressWindow(x, y, x+w-1, y+h-1);

    uint8_t data[] = { color >> 8, color & 0xFF };
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ST7735_DC_GPIO_Port, ST7735_DC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    for(y = h; y > 0; y--) {
        for(x = w; x > 0; x--) {
            HAL_SPI_Transmit(&ST7735_SPI_PORT, data, sizeof(data), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        }
    }

    ST7735_Unselect();
}

//void ST7735_FillRectangleFast(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, uint16_t color) {
//    // clipping
//    if((x >= ST7735_WIDTH) || (y >= ST7735_HEIGHT)) return;
//    if((x + w - 1) >= ST7735_WIDTH) w = ST7735_WIDTH - x;
//    if((y + h - 1) >= ST7735_HEIGHT) h = ST7735_HEIGHT - y;

//    ST7735_Select();
//    ST7735_SetAddressWindow(x, y, x+w-1, y+h-1);

//    // Prepare whole line in a single buffer
//    uint8_t pixel[] = { color >> 8, color & 0xFF };
//    uint8_t *line = malloc(w * sizeof(pixel));
//    for(x = 0; x < w; ++x)
//      memcpy(line + x * sizeof(pixel), pixel, sizeof(pixel));

//    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ST7735_DC_GPIO_Port, ST7735_DC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
//    for(y = h; y > 0; y--)
//        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&ST7735_SPI_PORT, line, w * sizeof(pixel), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

//    free(line);
//    ST7735_Unselect();
//}

void ST7735_FillScreen(uint16_t color) {
    ST7735_FillRectangle(0, 0, ST7735_WIDTH, ST7735_HEIGHT, color);
}

//void ST7735_FillScreenFast(uint16_t color) {
//    ST7735_FillRectangleFast(0, 0, ST7735_WIDTH, ST7735_HEIGHT, color);
//}

void ST7735_DrawImage(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, const uint16_t* data) {
    if((x >= ST7735_WIDTH) || (y >= ST7735_HEIGHT)) return;
    if((x + w - 1) >= ST7735_WIDTH) return;
    if((y + h - 1) >= ST7735_HEIGHT) return;

    ST7735_Select();
    ST7735_SetAddressWindow(x, y, x+w-1, y+h-1);
    ST7735_WriteData((uint8_t*)data, sizeof(uint16_t)*w*h);
    ST7735_Unselect();
}

void ST7735_InvertColors(bool invert) {
    ST7735_Select();
    ST7735_WriteCommand(invert ? ST7735_INVON : ST7735_INVOFF);
    ST7735_Unselect();
}

//void ST7735_SetGamma(uint8_t gamma)
//{
//  ST7735_Select();
//  ST7735_WriteCommand(ST7735_GAMSET);
//  ST7735_WriteData(&gamma, sizeof(gamma));
//  ST7735_Unselect();
//}
```

Comment: "it may affect the performance of LoRa" that, without much context, sounds wrong.

Comment: If your MCU is anyway busy sending stuff to a display, it will be busy even if two devices are on separate or same SPI ports, because in both cases you can't communicate with two devices at the same time.

Comment: For now i am using only the TFT and no other devices is connected t o the MCU, so itshould not be busy at all.

Comment: If TXE bit is not set, then it probably a configuration issue.  Did you enable SPI2 clock? How SPI2 is initialized? Are GPIO pins configured coorectly? Show `MX_SPI2_Init` and `MX_GPIO_Init` functions

Comment: @Flexz How do i enable SPI2 clock when i am using HAL?
For configuration i am using STM32CubeMX and for coding i am using Keil IDE